# Migrating from Swagger 1 to version 3

Tags: java, spring, swagger, swagger-3.0, wordnik

Working on some legacy code. So I'm trying to upgrade from wordnik libary to swagger v3.

```
<!-- Swagger writers -->
<bean id="resourceWriter" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ResourceListingProvider"/>
<bean id="apiWriter" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.listing.ApiDeclarationProvider"/>

<jaxrs:server address="/swagger" id="swagger">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="swaggerResourceJSON"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <ref bean="resourceWriter"/>
        <ref bean="apiWriter"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>

<bean id="swaggerConfig" class="com.wordnik.swagger.jaxrs.config.BeanConfig">
    <property name="resourcePackage" value="com.foo.fooo"/>
    <property name="basePath" value="/foo/V3/"/>
    <property name="title" value="Foo service integration"/>
    <property name="scan" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

So setup for looks something like this, in XML file.
My question, what alternatives for "resourceWriter", "apiWriter" and "swaggerConfig" in this case.
Because it is old code it was not done in Spring boot, but regular Spring.

Don't seems to find alternatives in v3 of Swagger for this classes.

Sorry for my bad english

Upgrade Swagger version